# Vector 2D erase element and keeping the field empty

Tags: c++

I know I should use int instead of int*, but is just to emphasize the case, my case is a bit more complex than that.

Let say I have as follows:

```
std::vector < std::vector <int*> > board;
board.resize(1);
board[0].resize(3);
board[0][0] = new int(5);
board[0][1] = new int(6);
board[0][2] = new int(7);
board[0].erase(board[0].begin() + 1);
std::swap(board[0][0], board[0][1]);
```

However I want to keep board[0][1] empty, so I can insert a new int(8) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't simply `erase` elements of a vector that are of a pointer types. You will cause a memory leak.

If you want to represent an *empty value* in a `std::vector` of pointers, there is a language feature created specifically for that purpose - a `nullptr`. Instead of erasing elements, like so:

```
board[0].erase(board[0].begin() + 1);
```

simply `delete` it (to safely overwrite it and cause no memory leaks) and overwrite it with `nullptr`:

```
delete board[0][1];
board[0][1] = nullptr;
```

When you need to overwrite that *empty value*, you can simply do so safely:

```
board[0][1] = new int(10);
```

This way, you effectively remove the unwanted element from the index `[0][1]`, mark it as an *empty value* and the overwrite it with new, actual value.